# Java Stream a Large SQL Query into API CSV File

Tags: java, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a Service that obtains data from large sql query in database (over 100,000 records) and streams into an API CSV File. Is there any java library function that does it, or any way to make the code below more efficient? Currently using Java 8 in Spring boot environment.

Code is below with sql repository method, and service for csv. Preferably trying to write to csv file, while data is being fetched from sql concurrently as query make take 2-3 min for user .

We are using Snowflake DB.

```
public class ProductService {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public ProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    }

    public InputStream getproductExportFile(productExportFilters filters) throws IOException {
        PipedInputStream is = new PipedInputStream();
        PipedOutputStream os = new PipedOutputStream(is);
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                Stream<productExport> productStream = productRepository.getproductExportStream(filters);

                Field[] fields = Stream.of(productExport.class.getDeclaredFields())
                        .peek(f -> f.setAccessible(true))
                        .toArray(Field[]::new);
                String[] headers = Stream.of(fields)
                        .map(Field::getName).toArray(String[]::new);
                CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder()
                        .setHeader(headers)
                        .build();

                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(outputStreamWriter, csvFormat);
                productStream.forEach(productExport -> writeproductExportToCsv(productExport, csvPrinter, fields));

                outputStreamWriter.close();
                csvPrinter.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warn("Unable to complete writing to csv stream.", e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) { }
            }
        });
        return is;
    }

    private void writeProductExportToCsv(productExport productExport, CSVPrinter csvPrinter, Field[] fields) {
        Object[] values = Stream.of(fields).
                map(f -> {
                    try {
                        return f.get(productExport);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .toArray();
        try {
            csvPrinter.printRecord(values);
            csvPrinter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("Unable to write record to file.", e);
        }
    }

public Stream<PatientExport> getProductExportStream(ProductExportFilters filters) {
    MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameterSource.addValue("customerId", filters.getCustomerId().toString());
    parameterSource.addValue("practiceId", filters.getPracticeId().toString());

    StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM  dbo.Product ");
    sqlQuery.append("\nWHERE CUSTOMERID = :customerId\n" +
                    "AND PRACTICEID = :practiceId\n"
    );
```

Comment: I think hardware can be scaled. To query the data fast from the sql server. Can you just check where the 3min time is consumed. Like for fetching data how much time its taking and for creating csv what's the time it's taking.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `Spring Batch`.

Comment: You should move outputStreamWriter.close(); and csvPrinter.close(); their own finally block or declare them outside the try block.

Comment: Why writeProductExportToCsv(...) method is getting called for each and every record? The .flush() operation is expensive and might corrupt your file accidentally if you call it for every record.

Comment: What DB engine are you using? Most of them _have_ an SQL export feature. Multi-core probably hurts more than it helps unless you prepare the database structure first.

Comment: hi @rzwitserloot we are using Snowflake https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Streaming*** allows you to transfer the data, little by little, without having to load it all into the server’s memory. You can do your operations by using the `extractData()` method in `ResultSetExtractor`. You can find javadoc about `ResultSetExtractor` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html).

You can view an example using `ResultSetExtractor` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_resultsetextractor.htm).

You can also easily create your `JPA` queries as `ResultSet` using `JdbcTemplate`. You can take a look at an example [here](https://www.netjstech.com/2018/03/jdbctemplate-with-resultsetextractor-example-spring.html). to use `ResultSetExtractor`.

Comment: does this allow streaming also? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_resultsetextractor.htm

Comment: If the `ResultSetExtractor` you mean, yes it allows streams.

Comment: The example you pointed to does not use streams, it loads all data into memory (an ArrayList).

Comment: Examples include the use of `ResultSetExtractor` only. It has already been indicated that this will be done with streaming.

Answer (score 0):

There is product which we bought some time ago for our company, we got even the source code back then. https://northconcepts.com/ We were also evaluating Apache Camel which had similar support but it didnt suite our goal. If you really need speed you should go to lowest level possible - pure JDBC and as simple as possible csv writer.

Nortconcepts library itself provides capability to read from jdbc and write to CSV on lower level. We found few tweaks which have sped up the transmission and processing. With single thread we are able to stream 100 000 records (with 400 columns) within 1-2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you didn't specify which database you use I can give you only generic answers.

In general code like this is network limited, as JDBC resultset is usually transferred in "only n rows" packages, and when you exhaust one, only then database triggers fetching of next packet. This property is often called fetch-size, and you should greatly increase it. By default settings, most of databases transfer 10-100 rows in one fetch. In spring you can use setFetchSize property. Some benchmarks [here](http://makejavafaster.blogspot.com/2015/06/jdbc-fetch-size-performance.html).

There are other similar low level stuff which you could do. For example, Oracle jdbc driver has "InsensitiveResultSetBufferSize" - how big in bytes is a buffer which holds result set. But dose things tend to be database specific.

Thus being said, the best way to really increase speed of your transfer is to actually launch multiple queries. Divide your data on some column value, and than launch multiple parallel queries. Essentially, if you can design data to support parallel queries working on easily distinguished subsets, bottleneck can be transferred to a network or CPU throughput.

For example one of your columns might be 'timestamp'. Instead having one query to fetch all rows, fetch multiple subset of rows with query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Product 
 WHERE CUSTOMERID = :customerId
   AND PRACTICEID = :practiceId
   AND :lowerLimit <= timestamp AND timestamp < :upperLimit
```

Launch this query in parallel with different timestamp ranges. Aggregate result of those subqueries in shared ConcurrentLinkedQueue and build CSV there.

With similar approach I regularly read 100000 rows/sec on 80 column table from Oracle DB. That is 40-60 MB/sec sustained transfer rate from a table which is not even locked.

Comment: we are using snowflake, and are looking at the actual java code, not just sql

Comment: Unfortunately I have no snowflake experience. Running query in parallel is all about java side programming. As you are already using executorService.execute(..) just run this one in a for loop and add clauses to query so each one can fetch distinguished subset of table.